# Gradle build process is failing

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

My project was successfully building and all of a sudden I got the below error in Android studio.

**Unable to find method 'org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publication.MavenPublicationInternal.getPublishableFiles()Lorg/gradle/api/file/FileCollection;'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.
In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.**

I tried clearing the local dependency cache and rebuilding the project. But still the error persists.
I am using android studio v4.0 with build tools v29.0.2.

Is it because gradle can't download the dependency from maven repo?
Is it because there is an error in configuring maven in my 'respositories' list?
How can I get more information on this error?

Comment: did you try the following - File - Invalidate cache/restart.

Comment: @cantona_7 yes I did.But the issue persists

Answer (score 21):

Try to update the [com.jfrog.artifactory](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.artifactory) version.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26900995)

Comment: @bartektartanus I did face the same issue when we increase the version of Gradle and it got resolved after increasing the artifactory library version. Gradle and artifactory publishing library should be compatible with each other.

Answer (score 8):

My resolution for this was to update the artifactory version like @disha4mourya suggested - add this block to your project's `build.gradle`, directly after your buildscript block:

```
plugins {
    id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "4.18.3"
}
```